# Good introductory texts on modular forms/L-functions

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I am relatively new to these areas but would like to gain some understanding through an introductory text. I am an undergraduate math major so ideally these books should be accessible to someone with only undergraduate algebra/analysis completed. Also, I would be greatly interested in a book that devotes some chapters to elliptic curves.